# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1280x5 and 6400x4096)?

Tags: matrix, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Defining Alexnet using the following code,I can train successfully.But when I want to see the output of each layer，it will be an error ‘RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1280x5 and 6400x4096)?’

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
      super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
      self.conv = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(1, 96, 11, 4),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.MaxPool2d(3, 2),
          nn.Conv2d(96, 256, 5, 1, 2),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.MaxPool2d(3, 2),
          nn.Conv2d(256, 384, 3, 1, 1),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Conv2d(384, 384, 3, 1, 1),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Conv2d(384, 256, 3, 1, 1),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.MaxPool2d(3, 2)
         )
      self.fc = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(256*5*5, 4096),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Dropout(0.5),
          nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.Dropout(0.5),
          nn.Linear(4096, 10)
        )
      
    def forward(self, img):
      feature = self.conv(img)
      output = self.fc(feature.view(img.shape[0], -1))
      return output
```

```
X=torch.randn(1,1,224,224)
for name,layer in net.named_children():
  X=layer(X)
  print(name,X.shape)
```

Could u help me？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to flatten the output array of `self.conv` in the for cycle. You can split it into two cycles, one for the convolution layers, and one for the fully connected ones.

```
X = torch.randn(1, 1, 224, 224)
for name, layer in net.conv.named_children():
  X = layer(X)
  print(name, X.shape)

X = X.flatten()  # or X = X.view(X.shape[0], -1)

for name, layer in net.fc.named_children():
  X = layer(X)
  print(name, X.shape)
```

Comment: Your approach is absolutely correct, thank you!